# Using DER key from Java in mbedtls Diffie-Hellman

Tags: java, c++, c, diffie-hellman, mbedtls

I have a Java application that is producing keys for a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. These keys are generated, and the public key is exported as follows:

```
/*
 * Alice creates her own DH key pair with 2048-bit key size
 */
System.out.println("ALICE: Generate DH keypair ...");
KeyPairGenerator aliceKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
aliceKpairGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair aliceKpair = aliceKpairGen.generateKeyPair();

// Alice creates and initializes her DH KeyAgreement object
System.out.println("ALICE: Initialization ...");
KeyAgreement aliceKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
aliceKeyAgree.init(aliceKpair.getPrivate());

// Alice encodes her public key, and sends it over to Bob.
byte[] alicePubKeyEnc = aliceKpair.getPublic().getEncoded();
```

Contained in `alicePubKeyEnc` is the public key I am sending over to my C++ application. As I understand it, this data is an encoded DER key for my DHE parameters. On the other side I am attempting to use this key with mbedtls as follows:

```
// An example DER (?) key from Java.
unsigned char buf[] = {
    0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x28, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x1b, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86,
    0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0c, 0x02,
    0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
    0xc9, 0x0f, 0xda, 0xa2, 0x21, 0x68, 0xc2, 0x34, 0xc4, 0xc6, 0x62, 0x8b,
    0x80, 0xdc, 0x1c, 0xd1, 0x29, 0x02, 0x4e, 0x08, 0x8a, 0x67, 0xcc, 0x74,
    0x02, 0x0b, 0xbe, 0xa6, 0x3b, 0x13, 0x9b, 0x22, 0x51, 0x4a, 0x08, 0x79,
    0x8e, 0x34, 0x04, 0xdd, 0xef, 0x95, 0x19, 0xb3, 0xcd, 0x3a, 0x43, 0x1b,
    0x30, 0x2b, 0x0a, 0x6d, 0xf2, 0x5f, 0x14, 0x37, 0x4f, 0xe1, 0x35, 0x6d,
    0x6d, 0x51, 0xc2, 0x45, 0xe4, 0x85, 0xb5, 0x76, 0x62, 0x5e, 0x7e, 0xc6,
    0xf4, 0x4c, 0x42, 0xe9, 0xa6, 0x37, 0xed, 0x6b, 0x0b, 0xff, 0x5c, 0xb6,
    0xf4, 0x06, 0xb7, 0xed, 0xee, 0x38, 0x6b, 0xfb, 0x5a, 0x89, 0x9f, 0xa5,
    0xae, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x11, 0x7c, 0x4b, 0x1f, 0xe6, 0x49, 0x28, 0x66, 0x51,
    0xec, 0xe4, 0x5b, 0x3d, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xb8, 0xa1, 0x63, 0xbf, 0x05,
    0x98, 0xda, 0x48, 0x36, 0x1c, 0x55, 0xd3, 0x9a, 0x69, 0x16, 0x3f, 0xa8,
    0xfd, 0x24, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0x83, 0x65, 0x5d, 0x23, 0xdc, 0xa3, 0xad, 0x96,
    0x1c, 0x62, 0xf3, 0x56, 0x20, 0x85, 0x52, 0xbb, 0x9e, 0xd5, 0x29, 0x07,
    0x70, 0x96, 0x96, 0x6d, 0x67, 0x0c, 0x35, 0x4e, 0x4a, 0xbc, 0x98, 0x04,
    0xf1, 0x74, 0x6c, 0x08, 0xca, 0x18, 0x21, 0x7c, 0x32, 0x90, 0x5e, 0x46,
    0x2e, 0x36, 0xce, 0x3b, 0xe3, 0x9e, 0x77, 0x2c, 0x18, 0x0e, 0x86, 0x03,
    0x9b, 0x27, 0x83, 0xa2, 0xec, 0x07, 0xa2, 0x8f, 0xb5, 0xc5, 0x5d, 0xf0,
    0x6f, 0x4c, 0x52, 0xc9, 0xde, 0x2b, 0xcb, 0xf6, 0x95, 0x58, 0x17, 0x18,
    0x39, 0x95, 0x49, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x95, 0x6a, 0xe5, 0x15, 0xd2, 0x26, 0x18,
    0x98, 0xfa, 0x05, 0x10, 0x15, 0x72, 0x8e, 0x5a, 0x8a, 0xac, 0xaa, 0x68,
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02,
    0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x00,
    0x2f, 0x6e, 0xa3, 0xd8, 0x5c, 0xca, 0x06, 0x99, 0xbd, 0x35, 0x90, 0xb5,
    0xc3, 0x11, 0xa6, 0x48, 0x5b, 0x5a, 0xe9, 0x14, 0xac, 0x4a, 0xed, 0x2d,
    0x46, 0xb1, 0x6b, 0xc7, 0x5b, 0x88, 0xc6, 0xa7, 0x51, 0x07, 0xa0, 0x4d,
    0x5f, 0xc0, 0x32, 0x54, 0x9d, 0x63, 0x35, 0xa2, 0x3b, 0x6a, 0x9a, 0x0a,
    0xb9, 0x46, 0xff, 0x0b, 0x78, 0x5d, 0xa7, 0x17, 0x94, 0x58, 0x28, 0x28,
    0xf2, 0xa0, 0xea, 0x3a, 0xf0, 0xe8, 0x8f, 0xc2, 0xa1, 0x7c, 0xb1, 0x50,
    0x38, 0xb7, 0x01, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x42, 0x30, 0x1e, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x17,
    0x46, 0xc8, 0x1f, 0xb1, 0xb4, 0xd2, 0xff, 0xf1, 0x32, 0xdc, 0xc2, 0xfc,
    0x2c, 0x15, 0xe4, 0xfe, 0xae, 0xb2, 0x1f, 0x8b, 0x20, 0x29, 0x87, 0xbe,
    0x31, 0x8c, 0xf2, 0x01, 0x95, 0x51, 0x35, 0x76, 0x4c, 0x83, 0xe4, 0x06,
    0x46, 0x96, 0x62, 0x42, 0x2f, 0x23, 0xb4, 0xb7, 0xc7, 0x41, 0x4b, 0x4e,
    0xf5, 0xab, 0x20, 0xb0, 0x45, 0x27, 0x52, 0x64, 0x63, 0x18, 0x87, 0x72,
    0xa7, 0x41, 0x80, 0xbd, 0x15, 0x4d, 0xa8, 0x48, 0x69, 0x69, 0x8b, 0x64,
    0x38, 0x03, 0xa7, 0x72, 0xf7, 0xeb, 0x2b, 0xdd, 0x19, 0x2d, 0x63, 0x3a,
    0xa6, 0x1b, 0x6f, 0xcc, 0x81, 0x14, 0xde, 0x29, 0xd9, 0x55, 0x66, 0xd1,
    0x95, 0x8d, 0x2f, 0x15, 0x5e, 0x29, 0xad, 0xf8, 0x82, 0xf0, 0x68, 0xac,
    0x65, 0xf7, 0x54, 0x4f, 0x3e, 0x52, 0x64, 0xe8, 0x28, 0x52, 0x0f, 0x7c,
    0xbe, 0xc4, 0xf2, 0x20, 0x40, 0x97, 0xfa, 0x0a, 0x78, 0x5b, 0x1d, 0xf8,
    0xdb, 0x15, 0x02, 0xbe, 0xc3, 0xf0, 0xb0, 0x3a, 0xda, 0x6a, 0xe6, 0x5f,
    0x74, 0x48, 0x74, 0x0e, 0xe9, 0x1d, 0x02, 0xda, 0x25, 0x37, 0x4f, 0x41,
    0x11, 0x63, 0x32, 0x93, 0x44, 0xfe, 0x5b, 0x3a, 0x7e, 0x25, 0xcc, 0x9f,
    0xd5, 0x99, 0x41, 0x9f, 0x00
};

size_t size = 557; // 556 + NULL terminating byte per the docs.

mbedtls_dhm_context ctx;
mbedtls_dhm_init(&ctx);
int res = mbedtls_dhm_parse_dhm(&ctx, buf, size);

if (res != 0) {
    printf("FAIL\n", -res);
}
```

`res` results in a negative, non-zero value (`0xffffcc1e`). I've checked the error codes for x509 parsing in mbedtls, but can't find a matching error code.

Any idea why I can't load this certificate?

**Update**

I updated my C code to print out the associated error message for mbedtls:

```
0x0000023c4f9fb2b0 "DHM - The ASN.1 data is not formatted correctly : ASN1 - ASN1 tag was of an unexpected value"
```

So I took the hex values from my key and ran it through [http://lapo.it/asn1js/](http://lapo.it/asn1js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hat links the the actual output from the key) which indicates some structure to my key and *seems* to parse the key just fine. Perhaps it's an issue with how I'm passing the key to mbedtls?

Comment: `size_t size = 557;` => `size_t size = sizeof buf;`. Why tag so much language ? I didn't understand what code cause you trouble.

Comment: I tagged it both C++ and Java because the public key is being exported from java and consumed in C++. I’m not sure what the problem is, but I suspect it is with the public key being generated in Java. I think it might not be what I think it is (der encoded public key). If I generate a key with OpenSSL the mbed (c++) code seems to work fine... it’s only the java key that is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong thing to mbed TLS's `mbedtls_dhm_parse_dhm`. That function expects the DER (or PEM) encoded DH *parameters*, not the key.

Using BouncyCastle's [`DHParameter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/+/master/bcprov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/DHParameter.java) you can get the DER encoded parameters like this:

```
DHParameterSpec dhParams = ((DHPublicKey) aliceKeyPair.getPublic()).getParams();
DHParameter dhP = new DHParameter(dhParams.getP(), dhParams.getG(), 0);
byte[] encodedParams = dhP.getEncoded(ASN1Encodable.DER);
```

This will give you the bytes that you can then pass into `mbedtls_dhm_parse_dhm`, either as raw bytes as you are doing now or PEM encoded as that function will accept that as well. Note that I'm passing 0 for L as mbed TLS discards it anyway. Also note that `getEncoded` throws so make sure to handle the exception.

Steps to complete a key exchange:

In Java:

```
KeyPairGenerator aliceKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
aliceKpairGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair aliceKpair = aliceKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
KeyAgreement aliceKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
aliceKeyAgree.init(aliceKpair.getPrivate());
DHParameterSpec dhParams = ((DHPublicKey) aliceKpair.getPublic()).getParams();
DHParameter dhP = new DHParameter(dhParams.getP(), dhParams.getG(), 0);
byte[] encodedParams = dhP.getEncoded(ASN1Encodable.DER);
byte[] javaPub = ((DHPublicKey)aliceKeyPair.getPublic()).getY().toByteArray();
```

Then in C++:

```
mbedtls_dhm_context ctx;
mbedtls_dhm_init(&ctx);
...
mbedtls_dhm_parse_dhm(&ctx, encodedParams, encodedParamsLen);
...
uint_8t mbedtlspub[128];
mbedtls_dhm_make_public(&ctx, 128, mbedtlspub, sizeof(mbedtlspub), mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &rnd_info);
...
mbedtls_dhm_read_public(&ctx, javaPub, javaPubLen);
...
uint_8t mbedtlssecret[128];
mbedtls_dhm_calc_secret(&ctx, mbedtlssecret, (size_t)secret_len, &olen, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &rnd_info);
```

And back in Java (assuming you encoded mbedtlspub from the previous steps in Base64, but you can do it however you want):

```
byte[] yBinary = Base64.decodeBase64(mbedtlspub.getBytes()); 
BigInteger y = new BigInteger(yBinary); 
DHPublicKeySpec dhPublicKeySpec = new DHPublicKeySpec(y, dhParams.getP(), dhParams.getG()); 
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM); 
DHPublicKey mbedtlsPubKey = (DHPublicKey) KeyFactory.generatePublic(dhPublicKeySpec);
aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(mbedtlsPubKey, true);
byte[] javaSecretKey = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret();
```

That completes the key exchange and at this point `mbedtlssecret` and `javaSecretKey` should match. So the data passing hands is `encodedParams` and `javaPub` (from Java) and `mbedtlspub` (from C++). I omitted some detail to focus on the core steps. Also note that a lot of these functions either return an error code or throw, so please take care using them.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Does this include the public key value from Java as well? I see the getP() and getG(); aren’t these just the prime and generator? What about about the encoded public key, Y, I think?

Comment: Correct, the mbedtls sequence is `mbedtls_dhm_parse_dhm` to initialize the context, then `mbedtls_dhm_make_public` to create its own public key after being initialized with the parameters, then `mbedtls_dhm_read_public` to perform the key exchange. The data going into `mbedtls_dhm_read_public` you can get with `((DHPublicKey)aliceKeyPair.getPublic()).getY()`

Comment: Ok, so I was able to set the public key with `mbedtls_dhm_read_public` and `getY()` from Java. How do I do the converse and set the public key from mbedtls in Java?

Comment: @Julio I edited the answer to include the steps to perform the key exchange. Hope it helps!

Comment: I haven't quite gotten it working. But you've definitely put me on the right track. Thanks for your help!